# Not generate model

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I added a model (.edmx file) for an existing database. The code in the Model1.Designer.cs file is not generated. Tell me, please, what are the ways to solve this problem exist for version 6.

Workaround similar problem to version 5 does not work, because the required properties of the new generator is not available.

Workaround:

> Change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer property to 'Legacy ObjectContext'.

not worked because this is proberty is disabled in property editor.

what am I doing wrong?

I am sorry, my pictures are not added:

- [designer file content](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22073104/3.PNG)
- [Model properties](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22073104/2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EF6 the only available code generation method is T4 templates. If you want to use ObjectContext instead of DbContext you need to get T4 templates that generate ObjectContext based context. You can get them from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a).